# unprotect and protect word document without changes

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop, word-2010

Given a protected **Word 2010** document with parts of the document not protected. Like one can type Text but not add new Styles.
When unprotecting via interop document.Unprotect("pwd") and adding a style.

**How to protect it again but keeping the exceptions in protecting that existet before unprotecting it?**
Interop only gives me [the values from the mdsn doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdprotectiontype%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Example via Word UI (translated from german UI):

- Open a protected document with some exceptions in protecting
- unprotect it

Now there is a Dropdown saying "No changes (readonly)" beside "Revisions", "Comments" and "Form fields"
If protected again it keeps al those exceptions that were set before unprotecting.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro in Word, and then inspecting the script that generates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed by Shaw I tried to record a macro again. And today it worked ;-)
Tried the same yesterday giving me some wired missing password exceptions when trying to open the macro.

Solution to my problem is to protect it without protection and setting only `EnforeceStyleLock` to `true`:

```
ActiveDocument.Protect Password:="xxx", NoReset:=False, Type:= _
    wdNoProtection, UseIRM:=False, EnforceStyleLock:=True
```

Comment: Don't forget to activate the checkmark next to your "answer" - you're allowed to do that on StackOverflow - so that others with a similar problem can easily recognize that the question has an answer :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. SO just tells me that I need to wait another 19h until I can acept my own answer.